# Not able to get Proper Date Time Format Using toLocaleDateString function in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization

I am trying for format Date Time based on Timezone and Locale of the user in javascript using following code. Which is running perfectly in chrome and giving desire output. But it is not working in Mozilla Firefox.

Below is the code:

```js
    var a = new Date("2019-09-05T07:20:04.000+0000");
    var l = "en-US";
    var k = "America/Los_Angeles";
    console.log(a.toLocaleDateString(l, {
        timeZone: k,
        dateStyle: 'short',
        timeStyle: 'short'
    }));
```

Output in Chrome (Correct) : 9/5/19, 12:20 AM

Output in Firefox (Incorrect, missing time) : 9/5/2019

As per the mozilla docs code is correct : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Comment: Actually, the is a Chrome problem, because you're using toLocale**Date**String - which is supposed to only return the date part. Use `toLocaleString` if you want time as well.

Comment: But still both are giving different format. Do we have logic to get identical output across browser considering Locale and TimeZone

Comment: yes, just use `toLocaleString`, not `toLocaleDateString`

Comment: But even with toLocaleString, not able to get identical result in both browser.

Comment: I'd suggest you post a new question with a snippet that shows the difference, using toLocaleString.